# Is there a way to look over the President's left shoulder?

Tags: saints-row-iv

In some over-the-shoulder third person games, you can toggle the right stick to swap which shoulder you're looking over, in order to shoot around corners or just because you like it better.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in Saints Row 4.

**Can you switch which shoulder you're aiming over in Saints Row 4?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not switch shoulder when aiming. It is believed that because the character is right-handed and looking from the left would be weird. There should be an option to make the character left or right handed.